# Setting dynamic UITableViewCell height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, height

I've got a UITableView with two dynamic rows. Each of the rows is a subclass of UITableViewCell and is loaded from nib. As my rows contain dynamic content, I use layoutSubviews to reposition all subviews:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
 [super layoutSubviews];

 CGFloat initialHeight = titleLabel.bounds.size.height;
 CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(titleLabel.bounds.size.width, MAXFLOAT);
 CGSize size = [titleLabel.text sizeWithFont:titleLabel.font constrainedToSize:constraintSize];
 CGFloat delta = size.height - initialHeight;

 CGRect titleFrame = titleLabel.frame;
 titleFrame.size.height += delta;
 titleLabel.frame = titleFrame;

 locationLabel.frame = CGRectOffset(locationLabel.frame, 0, delta); 
 dayLabel.frame = CGRectOffset(dayLabel.frame, 0, delta);
 timeLabel.frame = CGRectOffset(timeLabel.frame, 0, delta);
}
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to determine the height in table view delegate's tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: method.

The trick is that I load cell from nib, so just after it's loaded titleLabel.bounds.size.width is 300 px (as in nib), not taking into account type of the device (iPhone/iPad) and current orientation, so it seems impossible to calculate the height without conditional checks for orientation and device type. Any ideas?

Comment: You could as well say nothing. Any problems?

Answer (score 0):

Your `layoutSubviews` doesn't resize the cell, so the following should work:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return cell.frame.size.height;
}
```

If the cell needs to be resized due to the content changing then you can set `self.frame = newFrame` inside `layoutSubviews`.

You can also manual cause `layoutSubviews` to be called by calling `setNeedsLayout`.

Comment: I have already tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't work, because layoutSubviews is called after heightForRowAtIndexPath